# How to make multiple Ajax request in RxJS based on first response

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I'm using a redux-observable epic to fetch repos from a particular organization on GitHub using the search endpoint.  My main issue is i need to sort by "watchers" so I need ALL the repos, but GitHub only allows one to return at most 100 per page.  The response includes "total_count" which I can use to figure out how many more requests I need to make (# of pages).  Here is my code so far:

```
export const fetchRepos = actions$ =>
  actions$.pipe(
    ofType(FETCH_REPOS),
    switchMap(action =>
      ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=org:${action.payload.orgName}&per_page=100`).pipe(
        flatMap((response) => ([setRepos(response.items), setCurrentOrg(action.payload.orgName), fetchReposSuccess(response.item)])),
        catchError(error => of(fetchReposFailed()))
      )   
    )   
  );
```

I'm wondering how I use the "total_count" prop of the first response to make more ajax requests based on that number and merge into one stream without changing my code too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use the [`expand()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-expand) operator that recursively projects the response from the Ajax call where you can decide if there're more pages you need to grab. Therefore, you don't even need to use `total_count` because you can simply keep downloading pages until you get less items than your `per_page` param:

This is for example how I can grab all repositories from my account:

```
const PER_PAGE = 10;
const API_URL = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories';

const makeAjax = page => ajax.getJSON(`${API_URL}?q=org:martinsik&per_page=${PER_PAGE}&page=${page}`).pipe(
  map(response => ([page, response])),
);

makeAjax(1)
  .pipe(
    expand(([page, response]) => response.items.length < PER_PAGE
      ? empty()
      : makeAjax(page + 1)
    ),
    map(([page, response]) => response),
    toArray(),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

See live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-kccdwz?file=index.ts

Comment: Really cool, thanks!  When I look in the network tab of your demo I notice there are 2 requests per URL.  One of type 'fetch' and the other type of 'xhr'.  Can you explain?

Comment: One of them is always some service worker response, I don't know what stackblitz does with them, maybe they're just cached.

Comment: Is there a way to get all the items into one flat array before calling my other actions?  toArray() doesn't quite work for me.

Comment: You can collect all responses with `scan(...).takeLast(1)`